# How does the apt-plugin work?

Tags: android, android-studio, apt, dagger-2, generated

So,

- We are using `Dagger 2` in our Android application.
- Code generated by
  `Dagger 2` is located in `build/generated/source/apt`.
- In the documentation of [apt-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt) it states that :"*Using this plugin Android Studio will be configured to place the generated sources on the build path, preventing errors in the IDE*"
- If I remove `apt-plugin` from my `build.gradle` file, in a place where I use generated code I see compilation error. (Which is reasonable, generated code is not my source).

**The questions are:**

- What does it mean that `apt-plugin` configures Android Studio so that it places generated code to build path ?
- From what I know final `dex file` is generated from source folder that is specified in `build.gradle`, how do these generated files become the source ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-plguin` is a gradle plugin and as such it runs with your build script.

This plugin configures `apt` to be run with your build and sources to be generated. It further adds the path of the generated files to your source sets, which is why the build succeeds and Android Studio recognizes the files as well.

For further information you could always have a look on the gradle documentation on  [Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html).